# How to remove link below image (but keep on text)?

Tags: html, css, image, underline

I had a link with text and an image.  I don't want the image to have an underline under it but I do want the text to have an underline.  Is there anyway to support this without breaking these down into two seperate links?  Here is an example picture:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way to achieve that without splitting the link into two parts.

The alternative is to put `border-bottom: 1px solid #000` on to the element containing the text, however this will not behave in the same was as a native A element, with hover, active and visited states - at least not without the intervention of javascript.

Answer (score -1):

You could easily do something structured like:

```
<a><span>text</span><img /></a>
```

You could then remove the underline from `a` and apply underlining to `a span`.

Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/chrisvenus/pdrz9/

I should note that the following will not work:

```
img {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```